# SQL How do i find the average, minimum and maximum of contact duration per account

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im stuck trying to work out the average, minimum and maximum of the contact duration per account, im still new to sql so any help will be appreciated!

Here is a sample of the data im working on

```
ACCOUNT_NUM DURATION
11111   251
11112   121
11113   124
11114   514
11115   370
11116   160
11117   736
11118   291
11119   8
11120   8
11121   8
11122   225
11123   520
11124   9
11125   293
11126   9
11127   211
11128   697
11129   64
11130   725
11131   650
11132   135
11133   356
11134   80
11135   388
11136   452
11137   9
11138   415
11139   232
11140   284
11141   38
11142   225
11143   100
11144   289
11145   774
11146   214
11147   1,078
11148   359
11149   254
11150   1,806
11151   396
11152   412
```

Comment: don't paste links to images with data in them, instead show some sample (cut down) data in your actual question that can be used to answer the question. Also, perhaps be more descriptive and show what you have tried.

Comment: In your sample data, `account_num` is unique, so the questions don't really make sense -- the average, min, and max is the one and only value.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, you've hit upon "Aggregation 101". This is pretty much the first lesson.

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_NUM, AVG(DURATION), MIN(DURATION),MAX(DURATION)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NUM
```

They hide all the information on these [aggregation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) methods in the docs

- [`MIN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms179916.aspx)
- [`MAX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx)
- [`AVG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms177677.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_NUM , min(DURATION), max(DURATION)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NUM
```